# I can't send bitmap with Intent from internal storage

Tags: android, kotlin

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zm4hx.png)

in this situation, as soon as I selected Message App on share Intent, then message app open. But the system says "you failed to attach file to message..."

why this happens...?!

Comment: Post your `saveBitmapToJpg()`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please avoid adding images of codes. Copy and paste the codes with proper formatting. Even if you cannot use proper formatting, your questions will be edited by others to put them in the proper format.